# Include class definition file

Tags: node.js

How can I include a file, which contains classes definitions in my server.js file?

I don't want to use module.exports because I want to use this file in my client javascript code too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the module's contents to be available outside the scope of the file you have to use `module.exports`. Making the file also work in a browser just requires you to do some extra `if`/`else`s

For instance:

```
var self = {};

// Browser?
if(instanceof window !== 'undefined')
{
    window['my_module_name'] = self;
}
// Otherwise assume Node.js
else
{
    module.exports = self;
}

// Put the contents of this module in self
// For instance:
self.some_module_function = function() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Now if you're in Node.js you can reach the function like this:

```
my_module = require('my_module_name');
my_module.some_module_function(58);
```

Or if you're in a browser you can just call it directly since it's global:

```
my_module.some_module_function(58);
```

Otherwise I can recommend [Stitch.js](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch/) which allows you to develop JavaScript code using the CommonJS style `require` and modules, then compile it to also run in the browser with no code changes.

[Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) also allows for this type of functionality.

Here's another SO question about using the same code in node and browsers:
[how to a use client js code in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9735938/388916)

Comment: Thank you Codemonkey, i'll use the is/else method.